# Finding out which mode I am in with Braintree

Tags: python, braintree

Is there a method to call to see if I am in `Sandbox` or `Production` mode? Here is what I have so far:

```
import braintree
braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox, BRAINTREE_MERCHANT, BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY, BRAINTREE_SECRET_KEY)

>>> braintree.environment # how would I do this?
'Sandbox'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [braintree_python](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/braintree/configuration.py#L18-L19) source code (3.6), it would just be: `braintree.Configuration.environment`

Here's the relevant source code for your convenience:

```
class Configuration(object):
    """
    A class representing the configuration of your Braintree account.
    You must call configure before any other Braintree operations. ::
        braintree.Configuration.configure(
            braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
            "your_merchant_id",
            "your_public_key",
            "your_private_key"
        )
    """
    @staticmethod
    def configure(environment, merchant_id, public_key, private_key, **kwargs):
        Configuration.environment = environment
        Configuration.merchant_id = merchant_id
        # .. see more on github
```

So, in your example above:

```
import braintree
braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox, BRAINTREE_MERCHANT, BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY, BRAINTREE_SECRET_KEY)

>>> braintree.Configuration.environment._Environment__server
'api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com'
```

Comment: @David542 doesn't it make sense to just use https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/braintree/environment.py#L21-L23 instead? So `braintree.Configuration.environment.base_url` instead of accessing what python considers a "private variable" (denoted by _$CLASSNAME__$attribute). I thought you just wanted "Sandbox" not the URL.